# Refresh server side session when using Ajax Updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, updatepanel

I'm having issues refreshing the server session when using an update panel. I have three buttons that the triggers.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TrackingUpdatePaenl" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPopulate" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGo" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTopUpdate" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            //GridView that is updated by the triggers

        </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The issue that I am having is that the ServerState Session doesn't refresh itself after the Asynchronous postback. In my webconfig, I have session state and forms auth all set to 60 min time out. What is happening is that the page will timeout after 60 mins due to inactivity even while the page is active. I'm using this javascript to redirect the user once their server side session is timed out...

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
    // Handle the session timeout 
    string sessionExpiredUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/DealLog/Account/SessionExpiredRedirect.aspx";
    StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
    script.Append("function expireSession(){ \n");
    script.Append(string.Format(" window.location = '{0}';\n", sessionExpiredUrl));
    script.Append("} \n");
    script.Append(string.Format("setTimeout('expireSession()', {0}); \n", this.Session.Timeout * 60000)); // Convert minutes to milliseconds 
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "expirescript", script.ToString(), true);
 }
```

the above code is in the page load of my site master. This works well when not using update panels.

Users are complaining that it will time out after 60 mins even while they are using the page. I am under the impression to solve this issue is to use javascript to renew the session. Everything that I have found on the internet uses javascript to do this, but they call to the server on a timer and even if the page is inactive, the page will stay active. This is not a solution that I need. How can I refresh the server session on these button clicks? Once the user clicks the button, call the javascript to call another aspx page to keep the session alive?

I have tried the links [here](http://www.technade.com/2009/05/how-to-reset-user-session-in-iis-when.html) and [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=453) but I have had no luck with either of these. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which server OS you're on, but it could be that the App Pool is recycling after a certain interval.

[image: IIS 7 App Pool Advanced Settings]

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention that. I am using Windows Server 2008. I have already checked that setting and it is set to the default as shown above. For a temporary fix, I removed the update panel and triggers and it has not timed out improperly yet. Thanks for the idea though.